# Thunderbird keeps sleeping in the processes of Ubuntu

Tags: thunderbird, process

I am working with Ubuntu 13.04 but the problem was the same in the versions before:
many times when I want to start Thunderbird it rejects to start as "still running" and I had to "shut it first". When I look for it I find it through System Momitor under processes sleeping. There I first have to "end the process", then I can start Thunderbird. It happens with other programs also sometimes but most with Thunderbird.
How can I avoid this, that means: how to shut such programs, that they are really shut and not rejecting the restart?

Comment: can you please post your add-ons you have available in TB?

Comment: The Add-Ons: Adobe Reader 9.5, DIVX-Player, Gnome-Shell-Integration, Iced Tea, Quicktime, Shockwave Flash, VLC-Multimedia, VLC-Web - two I have disabled: Windows-Mediaplayer, iTunes-Application Detector

Comment: hello, with these add-ons, I can not suspect something that creates the problem. Is there any chance you have TB in start-up applications? Please go to System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications and check.

Comment: no, it is not in start-up applications. There I have just Mail Notification. My suspicion:  here is something in the configuration which keeps a seeping process. But it is not every time. I just cannot see when and when not.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have gnome-shell-integration in TB, I think that you do not need Mail notification in start-up applications. Please try to remove it from there (do not un-install it), re-boot and check to see that:

1. if you start-up TB you do not have same message
2. if you start TB and you receive new email, you get notification (in the bottom if you use gnome like I do or in the top with the blue icon if you use unity).

Then if both of the above are OK, then you can uninstall mail notification.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Have done as you have advised (deactivated Mail-Notification, rebooted). Still TB has slept as process and blocked from starting again. The Gnome-Notification I got, but now just if I opened TB, not independent from opening TB. Have to say: it is not every time, but sometimes, that TB sleeps and blocks. But I don't know why and when.

Comment: Can you please select safe mode to check if this happens? You can select it from help / restart with add-ons disabled. Otherwise, I only see to backup your mail folders (or your whole profile directory), uninstall TB, purge /home/.Thundirbird directory (hidden) and finally re-install it.

Comment: an other idea is to go to system monitor, right click TB process, select properties and check to see when this process was started

Comment: as I have said: it is not every time that TB remains a sleeping process. So if I know the start time, what can it tell me?

Comment: now TB was sleeping process again. This was shown under System monitor-processes-proterties:file:///home/horst/Pictures/Thunderbird%20sleeping%20from%202013-06-08%2011:48:20.png It is possible to see the screenshot? If not how to make it visible here?